# Combining CoreML and ARKit

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit, coreml

I am trying to combine CoreML and ARKit in my project using the given **inceptionV3** model on Apple [website](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/).

I am starting from the standard template for ARKit (Xcode 9 beta 3)

Instead of intanciating a new camera session, I reuse the session that has been started by the ARSCNView.

At the end of my viewDelegate, I write:

```
sceneView.session.delegate = self
```

I then extend my viewController to conform to the ARSessionDelegate protocol (optional protocol)

```
// MARK: ARSessionDelegate
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

        do {
            let prediction = try self.model.prediction(image: frame.capturedImage)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let prob = prediction.classLabelProbs[prediction.classLabel] {
                    self.textLabel.text = "\(prediction.classLabel) \(String(describing: prob))"
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unexpected error ocurred: \(error.localizedDescription).")
        }
    }
}
```

At first I tried that code, but then noticed that inception requires a pixel Buffer of type Image. < RGB,<299,299>.

Although not recommenced, I thought I would just resize my frame then try to get a prediction out of it. I am resizing using this function (took it from https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample)

```
func resize(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let imageSide = 299
    var ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: nil)
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(imageSide) / CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)), y: CGFloat(imageSide) / CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)))
    ciImage = ciImage.transformed(by: transform).cropped(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSide, height: imageSide))
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    var resizeBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageSide, imageSide, CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer), nil, &resizeBuffer)
    ciContext.render(ciImage, to: resizeBuffer!)
    return resizeBuffer
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not enough to make it work. This is the error that is catched:

```
Unexpected error ocurred: Input image feature image does not match model description.
2017-07-20 AR+MLPhotoDuplicatePrediction[928:298214] [core] 
    Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 
    "Input image feature image does not match model description" 
    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image feature image does not match model description, 
    NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4a49fc0 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 
    "Image is not expected type 32-BGRA or 32-ARGB, instead is Unsupported (875704422)" 
    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image is not expected type 32-BGRA or 32-ARGB, instead is Unsupported (875704422)}}}
```

Not sure what I can do from here.

If there is any better suggestion to combine both, I'm all ears.

**Edit**: I also tried the [resizePixelBuffer](https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/TinyYOLO-CoreML/TinyYOLO-CoreML/CVPixelBuffer%2BHelpers.swift) method from the YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph suggested by @dfd , the error is exactly the same.

**Edit2**: So I changed the pixel format to be kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA (not the same format as the pixelBuffer passed in the resizePixelBuffer).

```
let pixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA // line 48
```

I do not have the error anymore. But as soon as I try to make a prediction, the AVCaptureSession stops. Seems I am running into the same issue Enric_SA is running on the [apple developers forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80777).

**Edit3**: So I tried implementing rickster solution. Works well with inceptionV3. I wanted to try a a feature observation (VNClassificationObservation). At this time, it is not working using [TinyYolo](http://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph). The bounding are wrong. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: By far, the recommendation I'd give is a blog (http://machinethink.net/blog/yolo-coreml-versus-mps-graph/) and associated repo (https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph). Yes, this is as much about YOLO as about CoreML (and quite deep on ML), but the code has a good way to resize a UIImage as 224x224 and return a CVPixelBuffer. I commented on another question here about 2 days ago - you might find that code by searching on "pixel buffer" and "Swift", sorting by question date.

Comment: @dfd Tried it, the result (error) is the same. The project directly uses a camera session, it does not try to reuse the ARSCNView session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't process images yourself to feed them to Core ML. Use [Vision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_(Marvel_Comics)). (No, not that one. [This one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision).) Vision takes an ML model and any of several image types ([including `CVPixelBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880303-init)) and automatically gets the image to the right size and aspect ratio and pixel format for the model to evaluate, then gives you the model's results.

Here's a rough skeleton of the code you'd need:

```
var request: VNRequest

func setup() {
    let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: MyCoreMLGeneratedModelClass().model)
    request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: myResultsMethod)
}

func classifyARFrame() {
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: session.currentFrame.capturedImage,
        orientation: .up) // fix based on your UI orientation
    handler.perform([request])
}

func myResultsMethod(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
        else { fatalError("huh") }
    for classification in results {
        print(classification.identifier, // the scene label
              classification.confidence)
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44977400/957768) to another question for some more pointers.

Comment: Hello @rickster. It works fine with VNClassificationObservation, but I am having issues with VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation straight from the tiny-yolo example (https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph). It's like my bounding boxes are not having the right size. Pretty weird, but I can't figure why yet.

Comment: Hard to say without more detailed diagnostics (and it's a bit outside my bailiwick even then), but if I had to hazard a guess it might be something about pixel dimensions vs normalized image coordinates vs crop/scale option, with some possibility of video clean aperture also throwing things off.

Comment: @ina : I haven't given much time into it since then. But my most educated guess is that casting the request results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation] is not parsing the multiArrayValue of the observations the way it should. That would explain why the bounding boxes are off. I am not certain though, I would have to run the array through a matrix or something like that.