# Combining CoreML Object Detection and ARKit 2D Image Detection

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, coreml

The app detects specific 2D images (with ARKit) and has a mlmodel that detects some furnitures, the mlmodel is of type Object Detection, it is trained and works. Depending of what is detected I need to add some 3D objects to the scene or others.

I created an AR session with ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and I can detect the 2D image and in the method renderer(_:didAdd:for:) I add the 3D object and it works perfectly:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
        fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
    }

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
    configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = false
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

Also, I setup the mlmodel:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
    setupML()
}

    internal func setupML() {

    guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "furnituresDetector", withExtension: "mlmodelc") else {
        fatalError("Missing model")
    }

    do {
        let coreMLModel = try VNCoreMLModel(for: MLModel(contentsOf: modelPath))
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: coreMLModel) { [weak self] (request, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let results = request.results {
                    print(results.count)
                }
            }
        }
        self.requests = [request]
    } catch {
        print("Core ML Model error")
    }
}
```

By the moment I just want to print the number of results to see if the ml model detects something or not.

Until here everything works perfectly, I run the app and the camera shows fluid. Instead of intanciating a new camera session, I reuse the session that has been started by the ARSCNView as I found in [Combining CoreML and ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221746/combining-coreml-and-arkit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So my solution was use session(_:didUpdate:) to make the request to coreml model and continuously know if the model has detected something that appears in the camera.

```
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    DispatchQueue(label: "CoreML_request").async {
        guard let pixelBuffer = session.currentFrame?.capturedImage else {
            return
        }

        let exifOrientation = self.exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()


        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation, options: [:])
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the app it works but the problem is that the camera seems very slow and if I delete the code inside session(_:didUpdate:), the camera seems normal again. So the problem is here, I suppose that what happens is that it is not the proper place to make this request because this method is call all the time when detects a new frame in the camera. 
But I don't know where to do the request or what to do. Do you have any idea?

I will update it if I found some solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Your Core ML model might be too big and slow to keep up with the camera. A simple solution is to run the Core ML model less often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem is that the camera has a limited buffers available, I was enqueueing too many buffers while another Vision task was still running.

That is why the camera was slow. So, the solution is release the buffer before performing another request.

```
internal var currentBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    guard currentBuffer == nil, case .normal = frame.camera.trackingState else {
        return
    }
    self.currentBuffer = frame.capturedImage

    DispatchQueue(label: "CoreML_request").async {
        guard let pixelBuffer = session.currentFrame?.capturedImage else {
            return
        }

        let exifOrientation = self.exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()

        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation, options: [:])
        do {
            // Release the pixel buffer when done, allowing the next buffer to be processed.
            defer { self.currentBuffer = nil }
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can check the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_and_labeling_arbitrary_objects